# How can I get a block to display only on node view in Drupal 6

Tags: nodes

I have a block that I need displayed only on the main page of a node.

I can get it to display on `node/1/view` by putting `node/*/view` in the conditions, but that only works if view is in the URL. I want it to show whether I go to `node/1/view` or `node/1`, but NOTHING else. If I try `node/*` it shows it for every node page, not just `node/1`. I also tried `node/*/` but that didn't work at all as it appears the ending slash is being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the visibility textarea of your block, select PHP code and put the following:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && (arg(2) == '' || arg(2) == 'view')) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, this even works with taxonomy! Perfect! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want you can simply add `node/1` *and* `node/1/view` to the visibility list. However this is not the Drupal way imho - Drupal expects that default local tasks aren't explicitly specified in the URL (and this is why for example it outputs node URLs as `node/1` and not `node/1/view` in the first place). Path based rules like this can make a system more brittle - and doing it in a way that doesn't fit in with existing Drupal behaviour is asking for trouble imho. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I need it to be automatic as users will be signing up and getting a node page to customize. There will be thousands of them, and more added every day. Each node will act as a users own personal page and needs to have a block shown only on the main page of it (both node/1/view and node/1, but there will be thousands of nodes with this same setup). Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @Piontek Media So the problem is how to have the block display on some nodes and not others?

Comment: Not quite, the problem is how to have the block display on all nodes front page, and only the front page.